# Is it possible to share a specific folder on my network from two different OS's on the same PC and be accessed the same?

Tags: networking, dual-boot, samba, windows-10

I have a dual boot system running Ubuntu and Windows 10. I have setup sharing the second hard drive on the network on Ubuntu so that a media player on the same network can access the files. Is it possible to share the same data when running windows so that the same files are accessible from the media player when windows is running BUT look identical to the media player (meaning it should be just "192.168.1.2:/data" for the media player, ignoring which OS is running atm?

I tried using the same name for the share and enabled guest access in both OSes, but it was a no go. The other system sees it as a different location.

Comment: That is not what I am asking though. I have shared the folder in Windows, but I want the other machines on the network to see both Ubuntu and Windows share as the exact same share. Maybe it is possible through a samba setting, maybe not at all.

Comment: No, because both the IPs and the hostnames of Ubuntu and Windows PCs will be different. A much better solution would be to have a dedicated machine for samba server.

Comment: They both have the same statically assigned ip, so the ip is the same. Hostname also. Share name also. So in both cases I access 192.168.1.2/data, but if I map it on the media player and switch OS on the PC  it looks as unavailable network location.

Comment: Are you using Samba? I assume that you're using a 2nd PC running media player to access this share, correct? Does the share work when Windows is booted on the 1st PC, or does the share work when Ubuntu is booted on the 1st PC. If the problem is when Ubuntu is booted, in terminal, try the **findsmb** and **smbtree** commands and see what you get.